# PowerShell call operator with argument

Tags: powershell, arguments

**Sorry guys, i edit my post because you didn't have all informations**.
The goal of this script is to launch another script with arguments with elevated privileges

I call script like this:

```
./myscript.ps1 "ScriptName.ps1" "Argument1" "Argument2"
```

This is my entire script (myscript.ps1):

```
# ELEVATED SCRIPT
$ScriptName = $args[0]
$Argument1 = $args[1]
$Argument2 = $args[2]

If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator))
{
  # Relaunch as an elevated process:
  Start-Process powershell.exe "-File",('"{0}"' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -Verb RunAs
  exit
}
# Now running elevated so launch the script:
& $ScriptName $Argument1 $Argument2
Pause
# This function allows me to see variables content
function Pause ($Message="Press any key to continue…")
{
Write-Host -NoNewLine $Message
$null = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
Write-Host “”
}
```

Variables are null at this line:

```
& $ScriptName $Argument1 $Argument2
```

This script works if i change at the top of script:

```
$ScriptName = "mycommand.exe"
$Argument1 = "something"
$Argument2 = "something_else"
```

I hope it's clear enough this time.

Comment: Do you get any error messages or any output from the code?

Comment: `$arg[0]` -> `$args[0]`

Comment: There is an error on my post. It is args[0] and not arg[0].
When I make a write-host $mycommand before the Call Operator "&" i have a result. But after the Call Operato "&", $mycommand is null.

Comment: Then please [edit] your post and fix that typo. We can't help you when your question does not reflect the code you actually have.

Comment: Also, `$mycommand = $args[0]; & $mycommand` should work. If it doesn't work for you something else is amiss. Try starting a clean PowerShell console from CMD (`powershell.exe -NoExit -NoProfile`) and try again. Also check that the file you're running actually has the content you think it has (`cat .\script.ps1`).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem.
I stop trying to execute another script with elevated privilege.
I've modified my script to self elevated. Then, i don't have any problem about my variables.

Many thanks.